# python list intersection - regex match

Tags: python, regex, list

I have the following lists:

```
list1 = ['john mayer', 'elizabeth taylor', 'steven barber','jennifer richards']
list2 = ['john','jennifer']
```

I want to compare list1 and list2 and return TRUE since the first names match. I know that I can make this work by using set intersections if the full names were available in list2.. but that is not the case. Is there a regex matching version of set intersections

EDIT: Yes the result for the above example should be a true
If I have a list3

```
list3 = ['jack','jennifer']
list1-list2 : TRUE
list2-list3 : FALSE
```

EDIT2 : I think I was not very clear in my original post. In list2 or list3 I could have a combination of first names and full names

```
list4 = ['john mayer', 'jennifer']
list1-list4 : TRUE
```

Comment: I added to the end of my answer for your list4 case.

Comment: Can you complete the following English sentence please: "The result should be `True` if and only if ________, and `False` otherwise"

Comment: The result should be True if and only if members of list2 are a regex match with members of list1, and False otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def first_name_is_in(first_names, full_names):
    for name in first_names:
        for full_name in full_names:
            if full_name.startswith("%s " % (name,)):
               return True
    return False
```

Comment: @nitin, This doesn't work properly, for example: `'elizabeth taylor'.startwith('eli')` will return `True`

Comment: Now it fails for 'elizabeth taylor'.startswith('elizabeth taylor '). This is why the other answers here appear more complicated. They deal with both cases correctly

Comment: maybe i misunderstood,  but the OP is not comparing full name to full name,  he is merely trying to match the first name to a full name.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a set of the firstnames from `list1` like this

```
>>> {x.split()[0] for x in list1}
set(['john', 'jennifer', 'elizabeth', 'steven'])
```

You can do various set operations like this

```
>>> list2 = ['john','jennifer']
>>> set(list2).difference(x.split()[0] for x in list1)
set([])        # ie False
>>> list3 = ['jack','jennifer']
>>> set(list3).difference(x.split()[0] for x in list1)
set(['jack'])  # ie True
```

If you really need bools...

```
>>> bool(set(list2).difference(x.split()[0] for x in list1))
False
>>> bool(set(list3).difference(x.split()[0] for x in list1))
True
```

or the inverse...

```
>>> bool(not set(list2).difference(x.split()[0] for x in list1))
True
>>> bool(not set(list3).difference(x.split()[0] for x in list1))
False
```

For the new list4 testcase

```
>>> list4 = ['john mayer', 'jennifer']
>>> {x.split()[0] for x in list1}.union(list1) > set(list2)
True
>>> {x.split()[0] for x in list1}.union(list1) > set(list3)
False
>>> {x.split()[0] for x in list2}.union(list2) > set(list3)
False
>>> {x.split()[0] for x in list1}.union(list1) > set(list4)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> set(list2).issubset(ele.split(' ')[0] for ele in list1)
True
```

I removed [.] as I had in my original post, thanks to the point made by jamylak.

Comment: +1 Good solution but why not remove the `[`,`]` so you don't create a list comprehension?

Comment: Yes, [.] is not necessary here, so I removed them. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

```
full_names = ['john mayer', 'elizabeth taylor', 'steven barber','jennifer richards']
first_names = ['john','jennifer']

all((any(full.split()[0]==first for full in full_names) for first in first_names))
```

Answer (score 0):

As @gnibbler suggested it is best to make a set so i've changed mine to use that.

```
>>> first_names = {name.split()[0] for name in list1}
>>> all(x in first_names for x in list2)
True
```